# Inserting Value into User Defined Type

Tags: postgresql, user-defined-types

I have defined `SchemaTuple` as:

```
create type SchemaTuple as ("table" text, "attributes" text);
```

I would like to insert values into this but I am not sure how to go about this.

I tried declaring a variable first:

```
tuple SchemaTuple;
```

and then:

```
INSERT INTO tuple (table, attributes) VALUES ('tablename','attributename');
```

The problem is, I get the error:

```
ERROR:  syntax error at or near ","
```

where `,` refers to `(table,attributes)`

Can someone please let me know the correct way to do this?

Comment: are you using it in a function? Please post function code. Basically it is: `Select 'tablename','attributename' into tuple.table,tubple.attributes`

Comment: You cannot insert data into a type, it has no meaning. You can define table fields to be a SchemaTuple type. See http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/rowtypes.html on how to use composite types.

Answer (score -1):

You cannot insert a value into a type directly. You'll have either create a table for the type , or use the type as the type of an attribute in a table.
For instance:

```
--create type
CREATE TYPE PersonType AS (
    ID INTEGER,
    NAME CHAR(50)
);

CREATE TABLE Student OF PersonType (
    ID WITH OPTIONS NOT NULL,
    NAME WITH OPTIONS NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO Student VALUES (100, 'Joe');
```

or

```
CREATE TABLE Transcript (   
    COURSE CHAR(10),
    STDNT PersonType 
);
```

and then insert the value to Transcript table with value for STDNT specified as a Row type.